# Rails 3 Multiple Nested Routes Same Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have two nested resources which both use the parent controller. How can I change the param names so that instead of `params[:parent_id]` and `params[:id]` I get `params[:parent_id]` and `params[:child_id]`? Otherwise there is no way of determining which child I'm dealing with.

For now I'm mapping each individual child route `match 'child/:child_id' => 'parent#show'` but this breaks almost every rule of DRY seeing as I have about 5 such routes (and more to come).

Here is an example of my routes:

```
resources :parent do
  resources :child1, :controller => :parent
  resources :child2, :controller => :parent
end
```

Here is what I would like to do

```
resources :parent do
  resources :child1, :controller => :parent, :key => :child1_id
  resources :child2, :controller => :parent, :key => :child2_id
end
```

**Update**

I'm just going to redo the routes so the parent becomes nested under each child. The reason this was not done originally is because the former colleague who wrote them didn't know what he was doing.

This result will look something like:

```
resources :child1 do
  resources :parent
end

resources :child2 do
  resources :parent
end
```

Comment: Can you add your route code and a bit of your controller code please?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to only use parent_controller rather than having child1_controller etc.?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I'm just going to redo the routes so the parent becomes nested under each child. The reason this was not done originally is because the former colleague who wrote them didn't know what he was doing.

This result will look something like:

```
resources :child1 do
  resources :parent
end

resources :child2 do
  resources :parent
end
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems odd to make the parent a nested resource of child.  If you really want to use the parent controller (but I'm not sure that's the best way), one approach is to keep your original routes, which feels much more natural:

```
resources :parent do
  resources :child1, :controller => :parent
  resources :child2, :controller => :parent
end
```

and, in your controller, use `request.path` to distinguish its origins:

```
class ParentsController
  before_each :extract_child

  # use @child to find out which child it is...

private
  def extract_child
    request.path =~ /(child\d*)/
    @child = $1
  end
end
```

But frankly, I'd ask why do don't put the control logic into a ChildsController and treat it like a normal Rails-y nested resource?